# Importing c++ dll in c# project

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I am importing some c++ dll into a c# project, I am using visual studio 2010. I have succeded to import function that are using built-in type, however I am getting error when I have tried to deal with structure. This is a simple example:

c++ code

```
typedef long int TDate;

typedef struct _TMDYDate
{
    long month;                         /* In range [1,12] */
    long day;                           /* In range [1-31] */
    long year;                          /* In range [1600-] */
} TMonthDayYear;

int JpmcdsDateToMDY
    (TDate date,                        /* (I) TDate format */
     TMonthDayYear *mdyDate);
```

and I have translated to c# as:

```
   [System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TMonthDayYear {
    public int month;
    public int day;
    public int year;
}

public partial class NativeMethods {

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("MyDll.dll", EntryPoint="JpmcdsDateToMDY")]
public static extern  int JpmcdsDateToMDY(int date, ref TMonthDayYear mdyDate) ;

}
```

when I try to run the function in my test program I get this error:

**Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. at CsharpWrapper.NativeMethods.JpmcdsDateToMDY(Int32 date, TMonthDayYear& mdy Date)**

The struct are declare in the stack and I thought (maybe) was the problem but I am still getting the same error even though I have change TMonthDayYear to class.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the CallingConvention property in the [DllImport] attribute, this is Cdecl since you didn't use __stdcall in the native function declaration.  While that's wrong, it is not a great explanation for the AV.  You need to debug the C code, the AV suggests it has a pointer bug.  Project + Properties, Debug, tick "Enable unmanaged code debugging" and set a breakpoint on the C function.

Frankly, a date conversion like this should be written in pure C#.

Answer (score 0):

`TDate` type in native code is `long int` but in managed code it represented as int32 instead int64.

Comment: What are you talking about? Where in the sample code has the asker declared anything as type `Int64`?

Comment: @Cody Gray long int is Int64 while in code sample it is declared as int (Int32): native code: typedef long int TDate; int JpmcdsDateToMDY(TDate date, TMonthDayYear *mdyDate);

C# : public static extern  int JpmcdsDateToMDY(int date, ref TMonthDayYear mdyDate) ;

Comment: @Darius: That was indeed your guess (not an unreasonable one), but it was incorrect. The first person to point that out was Anton ("long ant int have the same size, so implementation of structure is correct"), the same person to post this answer. See why I'm confused?

Comment: Yes, guys. Im completly wrong. `long int` is the same the `long`

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be related, but you need the `[OutAttribute]` on the mdyDate parameter in order to write to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are an accustomed user in c++ you are probably familiar with pointers addressing the memory directly. Your error looks like a memory read/write protection related problem.

This is prohibited by standard nature of C# and u have to put the compiler in Unsafe mode.

If you code unsafe in c# u have to put code into unsafe mode.

```
   unsafe
   {
     // unsafe things
   }

   unsafe class Class1 {}

   static unsafe void someMethod ( int* cpi, int lngth) {...}
```

You also have to check the project configuration (**Build**-tab) and tack the checkbox for "**Allow unsafe code**".

I apologize if I was scrolling by some too obvious information. I will also state that this comment only has meaning if the situation is that C# going to address memory.